# What is a difference between service.yml and config.yml in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

In `config.yml`, I see root element such `monolog`, `web_profiler`. Are those services that can be configure in `service.yml` instead? In the other way, my service that defined in `service.yml`, are there possible to defined in `config_dev.yml`, `config_prod.yml` instead?

What is the difference in term of structure of `service.yml`, `config.yml` and the way framework interact with it?

Answer (score 1):

config.yml is global configuration which includes service.yml.

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
```

There is only logical difference. All parameters, which placed in your service.yml, you can place in config.yml

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that inside the config*.yml files, the so called semantic configuration takes place. Every bundle can expose such a [semantic configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html). The services.yml file instead is used to define services of your bundle.

So under `monolog` in the config.yml you configure the respective bundle. You don't define a service. The services of the `monolog` bundle are defined inside that bundle and you don't have to know about that.

If you have paid attention, you will have noticed that inside the services.yml the section starts with `services` and not the name of your bundle. That's because inside the `services` section you define services.

But to answer your second part of the question: Yes you can copy the contents of services.yml to config.yml but the strength of this separation is, that each bundle comes with a service configuration but you have one central config*.yml file for every bundle. Therefore it wouldn't be wise to copy your contents to this central file.